# How to run SQL Profile on AWS Aurora or Mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

What tool can I use to run sql profile against a AWS Aurora or AWS Mysql database?  Seems like a simple task that I have done many times against local mysql sql db or ms sql server, but for the life of me I cannot get to work. Is this something that can be done? I have been trying to use Neor Profile without success.  However, I'm able to use Neor Profile successfully on my local mysql db.

Because Neor Profile basically serves as a proxy, you have to use port 4040 in your application and then Neor connects to AWS via port 3306.  I can successfully get Neor Profile 'profiling' against the AWS db but when I run my local application or mysql workbench, via port 4040, it doesn't connect, with a general connection error.

My question, which I can't find by searching the Internet or help files is...Can you perform a sql profile against a AWS Aurora or AWS Mysql database?

Comment: You *are* using port 4040 and the address of your local machine, not of the RDS instance... right?

Comment: I am using port 4040 but not the address of my local machine. I just tried using localhost, port 4040 but does not connect. Of course I made sure Neor Profile was running when I tried to connect. Any thoughts?  Thanks.